# MovingPlatform - move position1 to position2 then wait for 3 sec

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have one PlatformManager (Script Attached)

One is Position-1

One is Position-2

One is MovingPlatform

I want.
MovingPlatform move Position-1 to Position-2 then wait for 5 Sec

then MovingPlatform move Position-2 to Position-1 then wait for 5 Sec

**Here is code for PlatformManager & its working fine without Wait**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform movingPlatform;
    public Transform position1;
    public Transform position2;
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    public string currentState;
    public float smooth;
    public float resetTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        ChangeTarget();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp(movingPlatform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void ChangeTarget()
    {
        if (currentState == "Moving To Position 1")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "Moving To Position 2")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 1";
            newPosition = position1.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        Invoke("ChangeTarget", resetTime);
    }
}
```

**I have tried this code but MovingPlatform didnt Wait**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestMovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform movingPlatform;
    public Transform position1;
    public Transform position2;
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    public string currentState;
    public float smooth;
    public float resetTime;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(ChangeTarget());
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3.0f);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp(movingPlatform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeTarget()
    {
        if (currentState == "Moving To Position 1")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "Moving To Position 2")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 1";
            newPosition = position1.position;
        }
        else if (currentState == "")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
        }
        Invoke("ChangeTarget", resetTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**Also i tried This but not success**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestMovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform movingPlatform;
    public Transform position1;
    public Transform position2;
    public Transform position3;
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    public string currentState;
    public float smooth;
    public float resetTime;

    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return StartCoroutine(ChangeTarget());
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp(movingPlatform.position, newPosition, smooth * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeTarget()
    {
        if (currentState == "Moving To Position 1")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        else if (currentState == "Moving To Position 2")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 1";
            newPosition = position1.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        else if (currentState == "")
        {
            currentState = "Moving To Position 2";
            newPosition = position2.position;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
        Invoke("ChangeTarget", resetTime);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

[**Here i attached Screenshot of Hirerchy & Inspector**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPi2m.png)

Also i tried other different MovingPlatform Scripts but MovingPlatform's movement is jerky when player ride on it.

Only this script. MovingPlatform's movement is smooth when Player ride on it.

Anyone idea how to solve this?

Comment: don't use strings for something like "currentState"... Make yourself an enum.

Comment: [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) is used to update physics, not translation. If you really need to use it for translation then use [`Time.fixedDeltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html) instead of `Time.deltaTime`.

Comment: i already said MovingPlatform's movement is jerky when player ride on it in other scripts.

Comment: i tried many scripts for that but all getting jerky movement.so, i used this. its movement is smooth when player ride on it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create some enumeration for your platform/paddle state

```
enum PaddleState
{
    Retargetting,
    Moving,
    Stationary
}
```

Now add some fields to your behaviour :

```
PaddleState paddleState = PaddleState.Stationary;
Vector3[] targets;
int currentTargetIdx = 0;
float stationaryFor = 0.0f;
```

Change your Update() method to only do certain logic when paddle is in the correct state :

```
void Update()
{
    if(CheckState())
    {
        ChangeState();
    }
}

void CheckState()
{
    switch(paddleState)
    {
        case PaddleState.Retargetting: // choose new target and reset stationary timer
            {
                stationaryFor = 0.0f;
                if(targets.Length >= currentTargetIdx)
                {
                    currentTargetIdx = 0;
                }
                paddletarget = targets[currentTargetIdx++]; // post increment 
                return true;
            }

        case PaddleState.Moving: // move paddle and check the distance to target, if distance is less than x then go to the stationary state
            {
                paddle.position = Vector3.Lerp(paddle.position, targets[currentTargetIdx], smooth * Time.deltaTime);
                return Vector3.Distance(paddle.position, targets[currentTargetIdx]) < 0.5f; // arbitrary distance 
            }

         case PaddleState.Stationary: // do not move for 3 seconds
            {
                stationaryFor += Time.deltaTime;
                return stationaryFor >= 3.0f;
            }
    }
}

void ChangeState()
{
    // go to the next state
    paddleState = (int)paddleState + 1 > PaddleState.Stationary ? PaddleState.Retargeting : (PaddleState)((int)paddleState + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script without states, just a small coroutine to achieve what you want :

```
    // Drag & Drop the platform gameobject
    public Transform movingPlatform;

    // Drag & Drop all the GameObjects (empty) the platform must go to
    public Transform[] positions;

    private void Awake()
    {
        StartCoroutine( Run() );
    }

    private IEnumerator Run( float duration = 5f, float waitTime = 3f )
    {
        int index = 0;
        float time = 0;
        WaitForSeconds wait = new WaitForSeconds( waitTime );
        while( true )
        {
            Vector3 startPosition = positions[index].position;
            Vector3 endPosition = positions[ (index + 1) % positions.Length].position;
            for ( time = 0 ; time < duration ; time += Time.deltaTime )
            {
                movingPlatform.position = Vector3.Lerp( startPosition, endPosition, Mathf.SmoothStep( 0, 1, time ) );
                yield return null;
            }
            movingPlatform.position = endPosition;
            index = ( index + 1 ) % positions.Length;
            yield return wait;
        }
    }
```

Comment: its work but MovingPlatform getting jerky movment when player ride on it